# pop up detail view out of tableviewcell

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitableview, core-animation

I am working on a app where I want to expand a tableviewcell to cover almost all the screen with animation when it is selected by user. I am looking to create a uiview on the tableviewcell and expend it to cover major portion of the screen when user selects the row.

The main problem I am having is to get the frame from where my pop up view will start expending. How will I get the frame of the row which is touched?

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

Is it crucial that the cell should not reposition?
If not ( i am guessing not, as you are anyway planning to cover whole screen):

When the cell is selected, scroll the cell to top (using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`) and either insert your custom view to cell's contentView or modify its parameters if its already there with different opacity/size etc

Answer (score 0):

Use [`UITableView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) function to get the rect for the row by passing the its `NSIndexPath`.

```
- (CGRect)rectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Thanks jhaliya for answering me me, this way I having a problem. If I have many rows and I select a row after scrolling down, the pop up view comes up from bottom. Instead it should have come up from the same position on the screen. I hope you understand what I mean....